# Calculate $\lim_{x \to 0} (e^x-1)/x$ without using L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

Any ideas on how to calculate the limit of $(e^x -1)/{x}$ as $x$ goes to zero without applying L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: Do you know what is the derivative of $x\mapsto e^x$?

Comment: $x\leq e^x-1 \leq xe^x$ an squeeze theorem

Comment: the basic fact is $e$ is defined as either $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n$ or $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k!^{-1}$

Comment: Some of the answers in other posts might answer your question. For example, see these questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152605/proving-that-lim-limits-x-to-0-fracex-1x-1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403876/show-that-lim-limits-x-to0-fracex-1x-1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using [Bernoulli's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), for all $x$ so that $|x|\le n$,
$$
1+x\le\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\tag{1}
$$
Therefore, letting $n\to\infty$, we get for all $x$,
$$
1+x\le e^x\tag{2}
$$
Furthermore, for $|x|\lt1$,
$$
1-x\le e^{-x}\implies\frac1{1-x}\ge e^x\tag{3}
$$
Thus, subtracting $1$ from $(2)$ and $(3)$ gives
$$
x\le e^x-1\le\frac x{1-x}\tag{4}
$$
Since we are looking for the limit as $x\to0$, assume that $|x|\lt1$. Whether $x$ is positive or negative, $(4)$ says that
$$
\frac{e^x-1}{x}\text{ is between $1$ and }\frac1{1-x}\tag{5}
$$
Therefore, by the [Squeeze Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), we get
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1\tag{6}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is really "without" Hôpitals rule for you but if you are allowed to use
$$
\exp(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}
$$
the limit is straightforward since this sum converges locally uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that when $x$ is very small near $0$, we have:

If $x > 0 \Rightarrow 1+x < e^x < 1 + x + 2x^2 \to 1 < \dfrac{e^x-1}{x} < 1 + 2x$, and letting $x \to 0^{+}$, we have: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \dfrac{e^x-1}{x} = 1 \tag{1}$,

and for $x < 0 \Rightarrow 1 > \dfrac{e^x-1}{x} > 1 + 2x$, and letting $x \to 0^{-}$, we have:
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^{-}} \dfrac{e^x-1}{x} = 1 \tag{2}$.

$(1),(2) \Rightarrow \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{e^x-1}{x} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^x=1+x+1/2x^2+\cdots$$

$${e^x-1\over x}={x+x^2/2+\cdots\over x}=1+\frac12x+\cdots$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}{e^x-1\over x}=\lim_{x\to0}1+\frac12x+\cdots=1.$$